# Windows 8.1 app exists in Windows 10 Store, but not in Windows 8.1 Store

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, windows-10, windows-store

Detailed explanation:

1. Windows 8.1 targeted app package bundle for x86 and ARM architectures was uploaded to the Windows Store;
2. Windows Store *approved* it as a valid app, and published it using targeted distribution (Beta release for specific e-mail addresses), and gave me two different links for each Store: Windows 10 - **www.microsoft.com/store/apps/some_code**; Windows 8 - **apps.microsoft.com/windows/app/some_other_code**;
3. Both links redirect to the same page in the web version of Windows Store (and instantly opens the Store App with the game page open): **www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/games/game-name/another_code**;
4. When you click the Windows 10 store link on Windows 10 machine, the Store App opens, and app is downloaded smoothly and easily;
5. BUT when you open the link to the Windows 8.1 Store on a Windows 8.1 machine, Store App opens, refreshes one time, but instead of displaying the app page, it shows the Home page, and *you cannot download the app at all from the official Windows 8.1 Store*, even though the browser page [includes Windows 8.1 in supported OS'es list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVSCo.png);

Some additional comments:

- in *both* machines I am connected to the Store using an account, which is in the list of targeted distribution partners (e.g. in the "whitelist" of beta users);
- App is *working normally* both on Windows 10 and Windows 8.1 when I am installing them using the ".ps1" PowerShell script Visual Studio generates when building a release package;
- I tried to change regions in the Store (UK, LT, US, etc.), but none of them works.

If you need more information - comment, I will try to explain more details :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I have found an answer here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/publish/set-app-pricing-and-availability

"If you want to hide your app in the Store but still make it available to certain people, select one of the following options to limit your app's availability. Note that customers on Windows 8 and Windows 8.1 won't be able to get the app at all if you choose any of these options."

Since our app was hidden, e.g. "targeted distribution" (with certain e-mail addresses in the "white-list"), we couldn't test the app in the Windows 8.1 store. (Don't ask why, but..) Microsoft does not allow this functionality on Windows 8.1 machines, as mentioned in the article above.

Comment: I have the same problem but my app was supposed to be a normal release. It shows support for win 10 and 8.1 but I can't find it in the win 8.1 store. Did you have this problem after leaving beta?

Comment: @fmtoffolo, if I remember correctly, after publishing the app, everything was working fine. I forgot all the exact details, since I left the project 6 months ago. Did you made both releases public (e.g. "Make this app available in the Store")?